# Which header should be used for FileSend Function?

Tags: c++, winsock

```
void FileSend(SOCKET FileSendSocket,char *FilePath)
{
    streampos filesize = 0;
    ifstream in(FilePath,ios::binary);
    ZeroMemory( &sendbuf, sendbuflen);

    if(in.is_open())
    {
        while(1)
        {
            in.read(sendbuf,sendbuflen);
            if(in.eof())
            {
                cout << "End of File sending from Client" <<  endl; 
                in.close();
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                send(FileSendSocket,sendbuf,sendbuflen,0);
                ZeroMemory( &sendbuf, sendbuflen);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I am trying to write a simple file transfer program.i see this code but i cant use.I have search but i could not find any example.

Comment: What is the error/problem?

Comment: The Win32 documentation clearly documents which header files are required for functions and data types. [`send function`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740149(v=vs.85).aspx), uses header `Winsock2.h` (see the bottom of that link).

Comment: Side note: `if(in.eof())` is wrong (you do it wrong as almost anybody)

Comment: #include <fstream>
#include <iostream> i added and solved my problem thx :)